# How to execute command on linux plateform with different thread in python?

Tags: python, multithreading

I want to execute two separate commands on command prompt and read command's output in python. My approach is, I want to execute these command on certain **time interval** i.e. after x seconds.

I have two commands say **command1** and **command2**. command1 is taking maximum **30 seconds** to print it's output on console. command2 is taking maximum **10 seconds** to print it't output on console.

I want to execute this command1 and command2 with new thread every time (time interval) i.e. after every x seconds

**program code -**

```
import os,sys
import thread,threading
import time

def read_abc_data():

    with open("abc.txt", "a") as myfile:
        output = os.popen('command1').read()
        myfile.write(output +"\n\n")

def abc(threadName):

    while True:
        threading.Thread(target = read_abc_data).start()
        time.sleep(10)

def read_pqr_data():

    with open("pqr.txt", "a") as myfile:
        output = os.popen('command2').read()
        myfile.write(output +"\n\n")

def pqr(threadName):

    while True:
        threading.Thread(target = read_pqr_data).start()
        time.sleep(10)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    try:
        thread.start_new_thread( abc, ("Thread-1",  ) )
        thread.start_new_thread( pqr, ("Thread-2",  ) )
    except:
        print "Error: unable to start thread"

    while 1:
        pass
```

Currently I have given 10 seconds sleep (delay) to execute read_abc_data() and read_pqr_data() functions. after executing this program for 1 minute I'm getting abc.txt file as empty. I think the reason is command1 didn't provide complete output in 10 seconds. right?

I want abc.txt and pqr.txt files with commands output as data in that. Is I'm missing something?

Comment: Does `command1` output while it is running or at the end of its execution?

Comment: @Kadir- command1 and command2 outputs while running only.

Comment: So you'd better do it with `subprocess` and `readline` to get output while running instead of `os.popen`

Answer (score 0):

As commands output while running, so you'd better get outputs streamingly. It can be done with `subprocess` and `readline`:

```
import subprocess

def read_abc_data():
    with open("abc.txt", "a") as myfile:
        process = subprocess.Popen('command1', stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        for line in iter(process.stdout.readline, ''):
            myfile.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. It uses locks to lock the file resource during updates, and uses a single function that gets executed as part of thread execution.

```
    import time    
    import subprocess    
    import threading    
    from thread import start_new_thread

    command1 = "ls"    
    command2 = "date"    
    file_name1 = "/tmp/one"    
    file_name2 = "/tmp/two"


    def my_function(command, file_name, lock):
        process_obj = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        command_output, command_error = process_obj.communicate()
        print command_output
        lock.acquire()
        with open(file_name, 'a+') as f:
            f.write(command_output)
            print 'Writing'
        lock.release()


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        keep_running = True
        lock1 = threading.Lock()
        lock2 = threading.Lock()
        while keep_running:
            try:
                start_new_thread(my_function, (command1, file_name1, lock1))
                start_new_thread(my_function, (command2, file_name2, lock2))
                time.sleep(10)
            except KeyboardInterrupt, e:
                keep_running = False
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and why it solves the problem will improve the answer's long-term value.